# Updating multiple check_box_tag in show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update multiple check boxes in my show page . I am really stuck on how to do this and a lot of the help online has really confused me. I am still a rails noob. im using rails 4.

`*Edit*`

the error i currently get is 
`Missing template lottery/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.`

Here is  my controller for my page

```
class LotteryController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:new, :show,:update]

  def new
    @winner = Lottery.pickWinner()
  end

  def show
    @conferences = Conference.all
    #@lead = Lead.all
    @leads = Lead.new
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

and my show.html.erb page for this controller

```
     <body> 
      <%= form_tag do %>
    <% @conferences.each  do |c| %>

    <table class = 'table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered table-  condensed'>
        <h1> Conference : <%= c.name %> </h1>
        <tr>
            <td><b>First Name</b></td>  
            <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Email</b></td>   
            <td><b>Department</b></td>  
            <td><b>Title</b></td>
            <td><b>Company</b></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <% @leads.get_lead_by_conference(c.id).each do |l| %>
                <td>  <%= l.lead_first_name %> </td>
                <td>  <%= l.lead_last_name  %> </td>
                <td> <%= l.email %> </td>
                <td> <%= l.department %></td>
                <td> <%= l.title %> </td> 
                <td><%=l.account_name %> </td>

            <td><label for="lead">Enable for Lottery</label><br/>
        <%= check_box_tag "leads_checkbox[]",l.id %> <%= l.lotter_flag %> 

            </td>

        </tr>
            <% end %>
    </table>    

   <% end %>
 <%= submit_tag "select Winners" %> 
  <%end %> 


</body>
```

`Edit my get_lead_by_conference_id(conf_id ) under Lead model`

```
def get_lead_by_conference(conf_id)
        #  get all leads that correspond with conf id
     Lead.where(:conference_id => conf_id)
end
```

so what i am exactly trying to do is in my show page i have multiple tables separated by these conferences. In each conference i have a lead and i want to select a winner in each conference for a lottery. the attribute in the Leads model that is a boolean is `lotter_flag`. I want to update all those leads with the marked checked box after clicking the submit  button. A few things that has stomped is that im updating the Leads model under a different controller.   Thanks in advance and i do apologize if i have format errors.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @pavan not at the moment but i feel like this is wrong functionality wise. my submit button does nothing at the moment and i dont know what i have to do to make it work

Comment: Post your `get_lead_by_conference_id` method.

Comment: @pavan i have posted it .

Comment: Ok but you are giving each on `@leads` which is `Lead.new`.How is that possible?

Comment: well i believe this is working because i am returning each lead that belongs to a given conference. this is achieved by `Lead.where(:conference_id => conf_id)`

Comment: @pavan is there a distinct way to update multiple check boxes with a single button?

Comment: Can you post the `params` after clicking the `submit button`?

Comment: in this code my submit buttone doesnt do anything. idk how to go about  saving the checked boxes. when i click submit it gives me a routing error

Comment: Can you the post the error in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `show method`,you have given **`@lead = Lead.all`** and in the `show.html.erb`,you are using **`@leads`** which is actually given as **`Lead.new`** in the `show method`.It doesn't make any sense and literally you are performing **`each`** on **`Lead.new`** which is wrong.

Try changing your `show method` like this

```
def show
@conferences = Conference.all 
@leads = Lead.all
@lead = Lead.new 
end
```

**Note:**
And as per the `Rails Covention`,Controller classnames should be **`plural`**.In your case it should be **`LotteriesController`** not **`LotteryController`**. Although now the **`convention`** is not the issue but it is always recommended.

**Update**

With regarding to your error,Rails is actually looking for file called **`create`**.

You should be changing the form_tag in your **`show.html.erb`** like this

```
<%= form_tag :action => "create" do %>
```

and also you should be having a **`create`** method in your controller.

Comment: im actually not using `@lead` anymore. i forgot to erase that. The reason why i have it as `@leads` = Lead.new is because i was to use the method `get_lead_by_conference_id(c.id)` .